# Using a variable name in a list to name a list entry in R

Tags: r, list

I am new to working with lists in R and thus I am having trouble assigning a name to a my list entries instead of the generic numbering system. I have a list that has entries that follow the same format. instead of having $`1` as the list entry name, I would like to assign the value under 'Variable Name'. So the name for the first entry would be NOTICE, second entry would be MONTHS, etc.

```
print(cda)
$`1`
                            664                                
category                    "Changes in Daily Activity"        
Variable Name               "NOTICE"                           
Variabe Description / Label "When did you first notice decline"
Variable Format             "DATE9."                           
Variable Allowable Values   ""                                 
Method of Data Collection   "Informant"                        
Data Type                   "Num"                              

$`2`
                            665                        
category                    "Changes in Daily Activity"
Variable Name               "MONTHS"                   
Variabe Description / Label "Number of months elapsed" 
Variable Format             "3."                       
Variable Allowable Values   ""                         
Method of Data Collection   "Informant"                
Data Type                   "Num"                      

....                                 

$`6`
                            670                                                                                                   
category                    "Changes in Daily Activity"                                                                           
Variable Name               "COURMEM"                                                                                             
Variabe Description / Label "Has the course of the decline been a steady downhill progression or have there been abrupt declines?"
Variable Format             "1."                                                                                                  
Variable Allowable Values   "1 = Steady\n2 = Abrupt\n3 = Not Known"                                                               
Method of Data Collection   "Informant"                                                                                           
Data Type                   "Num"
```

Comment: something like `names(cda) <- sapply(cda, \`[[\`, "Variable Name")`

Comment: This is not strictly related (unsolicited advice) but you might also want to consider how you create the list in the first place, for example, looks like you are using the `row.names` to keep valuable information and `664`, `665` look like case numbers. How about reshaping the data so that you can have a `data.frame` where your current `row.names` are the columns and your case numbers are a generic `ID` column. If you want to keep them as a list you can also do so splitting the `data.frame` by ID

Comment: The 664, 665, etc. are row numbers of the original dataframe. My process in creating the lists: 1) subset my dataframe by category 2) create a list entry for each row in that subset. The issue is I have to transpose each row so each entry in the list is vertical for when I print the list in Rmd.  When I transpose the list, the row number becomes the second column header. Is there a way for that to not occur? Here is my list fx:
  get_lists <- function(df, target) {
    sub <- subset(df, category == target)
    label <- sub$category[1]
    split(sub, seq(nrow(sub))) %>%
    lapply(t)
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to extract value with rowname as `'Variable Name'` from each list and assign it to names of the list. Using base R you can do this as :

```
names(cda) <- sapply(cda, function(x) x['Variable Name', ])
```